# what is the better practice to allocate 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I am writing a program for MD simulation, in which I need to use dynamically allocated 2D array. For performance reasons, I want the memory the the 2D array is **a consecutive chunk**. There are two ways I know to do this

1. Use VLA in C99.

```c
size_t rows, cols;
int (*arr)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *arr * rows);
if (arr)
{
  // do something here

  free(arr);
}
```

2. Use pointer to pointer

```c
int **create(int **arr, int rows, int cols)
{
  int nbytes = sizeof(int) * rows * cols;
  int *data = (int *) malloc(nbytes);
  nbytes = sizeof(int *) * rows;
  arr = (int **)malloc(nbytes);
  int n = 0;
  for (int i=0; i <rows; i++){
    arr[i] = &data[n];
    n += cols;
    }
  retrun arr;
 }
void destroy(int **arr)
{
  if (arr == NULL) return;
  free(arr[0]);
  free(arr);
}
```

I am wondering which of the two is better for practice, or there is another even better solution? To me, the first one is **more concise**, but because the 2d array will be used as **argument passing** to functions very often, it seems the second one is better. I am not an expert on programming so I would like to listen to your opinions. Thanks.

Comment: One factor to consider is whether you are going to be passing these 2D arrays to any existing APIs. E.g. if an existing API expects an `int **` then it would be foolish to use method (1).

Comment: you mean people use the second one more often than the first one?@Paul R

Comment: @PaulR You could use method 1 and also set up an array of pointers for passing to those API functions. If contiguous memory is advantageous to your application of course.

Comment: Method 2 is actually incorrectly coded. I guess you were intending to allocate a contiguous block and then allocate pointers pointing to each row of that block. But it would still be simpler to use Method 1 and then tack on `int *row_pointers[rows];`

Comment: @wallen Where is data used in statement *data = (int *) malloc(nbytes); declared?!

Comment: Your first method doesn't use a VLA, but a VM type.  Your difficulty to code that stuff correctly proves that the first has to be preferred.  That is what the C standard gives you, it is simple to use and efficient. What do you want more?

Comment: I'd *only* use method #2 *if* I had to have a *non-rectangular* array, i.e. one where the there are rows or columns of different lengths, like in an array of strings `char* myStrings[]`.

Comment: @HannoBinder I think you misread (I did too initially), it is not allocating a jagged array

Comment: @Matt McNabb yes, missing one sentence...now corrected

Comment: @MattMcNabb I guess that's my point: If you don't need some kind of jagged array, don't use method #2. - Or am I still mislead?

Comment: @HannoBinder method 2 is not a jagged array  ... so if you do need a jagged array you can't use either method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first method will guarantee that the memory is allocated in a single, contiguous block.  The second method does not guarantee that rows will be adjacent in memory (most likely, they will not be).

The main hitch is that the types `int (*)[N]` and `int **` are not compatible, and simply casting one to the other won't do what you want.  If you're using an API that expects `int **`, then you'll need to use the second method.

As far as passing each as arguments, there's no practical performance difference; they're both pointer types.  The only real issue is that

```
void func( size_t cols, size_t rows, int (*arr)[cols] )
```

may be a little more awkward to read than

```
void func ( int **arr, size_t rows, size_t cols )
```

If you're not relying on any external API and have total control of how you implement things, use the first method.  It's cleaner in terms of code, it guarantees contiguous memory, and it's easier to manage.  The tradeoff is some ever-so-slightly gnarly syntax.